# When to use imparfait or passé composé for simultaneous actions?

Tags: temps-grammatical, conjonctions, passé-composé, imparfait

I would like to know whether the following sentences are correct:

(in the spirit of “When X was happening, Y happened” or “when X happened, Y was happening”)

- Les enfants regardaient la télé quand les parents sont revenus de leur
  soirée.
- Quand je suis entré dans la salle, tout le monde buvait du
  champagne.
- Quand j'ai passé l'examen, je connaissais très bien mon sujet

I am not sure, especially about the second one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's totally correct!

Passé composé implies an action that started in the past and that is over. It's a ponctual action.

Imparfait is used for lasting actions in the past.

Comment: Lasting actions in the past that may or may not be terminated in the present and also habitual past.