# Does the Past Participle in a sentence stay the same when avoir is used?

Tags: grammaire, participe-passé, passé-composé

It says in a textbook on this website (personactivelearn) that when you are using the auxiliary of 'avoir' in a past tense sentence that the past participle doesn't change to agree with the subject.... par exemple:

J'ai fait
Tu as fait
Il/Elle/On a fait

Is this just the rule for the verb 'faire' or is it true that the past participle doesn't change when the auxiliary verb is avoir??

Because i seem to think that 'manger' would be:

Elle a mangée or
Ils ont mangés

Let me know if im wrong. Sorry about massive text^^

Comment: Several questions already asked about this. [Agreement with a plural noun in passé composé](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/7280/358), Agreement of the COD with “avoir” [duplicate](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/9631/358)

Comment: In conjugations, it does not change. Elle a mangé. Except with a direct object in the feminine, feminine plural or masculine plural: les, la, Elles les a mangées [les pommes]; elle les a mangés [le poisson]. Il a fait les travaux. Il les a faits [silent s] la semaine dernière. ***But the tricky bit is not even that.*** The tricky bit is ***getting the pronunciation right when there is an e or es added as in***: Elle a fait des glaces maisons. Et elle les a ***faites*** l'année dernière, Pronounced: faite, the s is silent, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the past participle does not change with the auxiliary avoir, except for the case it is placed before the verb and there is a `Complement d'objet direct-COD` in the sentence. In this case the participle will inherit from the COD.

For example:

Le singe a volé une `pomme`. The participle does not change. Pomme is the COD.

`La pomme` que le singe a volé**e** est rouge. The participle changes.

`Les pommes` que le singe a volé**es** sont rouges. Changes too.

Comment: Would the verb 'manger' not change then? Would it stay as:

Comment: J'ai mangé, Tu as mangé, il a mangé etc or would it be elle a mangée?

Comment: Elle a mangé, j'ai mangé and so on but: les frites qu'elle a mangées

Comment: Can't you just say direct object pronoun in English?

Comment: @BenjaminCutting But *les frites sont mang**ée**s*. Detailed in this [very clear answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7281/358).

Comment: Sorry @Lambie english is not my native language and I couldn't remember the term when I wrote the answer

Comment: No problem. I just see people doing that a lot. I didn't mean to "take it out" on you. :)