# Passé composé vs imparfait: when to use which?

Tags: verbes, temps-grammatical, passé-composé, imparfait

I am currently learning the *imparfait* tense, and I am confused about how it is different from the *passé composé*?

In which cases would I use the *imparfait* instead of *passé composé*, and vice versa?

Comment: peut-être ici ? http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7247/when-to-use-imparfait-or-passe-compose-for-simultaneous-actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *passé composé* is used to narrate individual events in the past.
Whereas the *imparfait* is used to

- describe the past
- express habitual, repetitive action
- describe past events that were repeated.

These are just some of the differences.