# Adjectif "vexé"

Tags: grammaire, verbes, adjectifs

Pourquoi on utilise passé composé au lieu d'imparfait avec l'adjectif "vexé"?

> ... et j'ai été un peu vexée.

Comment: Ça dépend du contexte.

Comment: Merci de donner du contexte, l'utilisation de l'imparfait ou de tout autre temps n'a rien avoir avec le sens du mot utilisé dans la phrase. "J'étais vexé"  pourrait être correct dans certain contexte.

Comment: Question similaire: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29233/phrase-comportant-%c3%aatre-commenc%c3%a9e

Answer (score 3):

1/ Dans ta phrase, il n'y a pas de plus que parfait. Juste un passé composé : J'**ai été**, passé composé du verbe être (avec l'auxiliaire *avoir* conjugué au présent).

2/ Comme tu l'as observé, dans cette phrase, *vexée* n'est pas un participe passé mais bien un **adjectif**.

3/ Rien n'empêcherait d'utiliser l'imparfait plutôt que le passé composé. Imparfait du verbe *être* donc : *J'**étais** un peu vexée*

Peut-être est-ce cette dernière forme qui te fait penser à un plus que parfait mais... il n'en est rien puisque *vexée* reste, là encore, un adjectif.

Le choix entre le participe passé et l'imparfait n'est pas ici dépendant de l'adjectif, il entre dans le cas général tel qu'examiné [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25117/imparfait-or-pass%C3%A9-compos%C3%A9).

Comment: Il s'agit bien d'un participe passé.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher : lol! Quel est l'intitulé de la question de l'OP ? Sur quoi la question de l'OP porte-t-elle ? Sur vexé pris comme pp ou comme adj ? Désolé, mais moi, je ne réponds pas aux questions en affirmant que la question est fausse. ;-)

Comment: Ce n'est pas un adjectif, c'est une phrase passive (dans ce contexte). OP se troumpe en considérant que c'est un adjectif.

Answer (score 3):

La problématique telle qu'exposée me laisse un peu perplexe. À l'école primaire (euh, il y a fort longtemps en ce qui me concerne), on disait « participe passé employé comme adjectif », donc une forme verbale mais un emploi d'épithète (une mine vexée) ou d'attribut du sujet (je suis vexé) voire d'attribut du complément d'objet direct (« Il trouva le général Giraud vexé de n'avoir pu […] »).

À mon sens, si c'était un honnête participe passé, on éviterait alors le passif au profit de la voie active (« Il m'a vexé »).

Comment: Pour ne pas preciser qui l'a vexe ? La voix passive est tout a fait justifiee. La version attribut du sujet est une voix passive aussi.

Comment: @Matthieu Brucher – pourquoi pas, si l'on sous-entend un complément d'agent qu'on ne veut en l'occurrence pas nommer ; en revanche, « je suis vexé » peut désigner mon état présent (verbe être non en tant qu'auxiliaire mais en tant que verbe d'état). Vexé est donc tantôt un participe passé, entrant ou non dans la composition d'un temps périphrastique tel le passé composé, tantôt … un participe passé employé comme adjectif, cité alors tel quel sans idée de conjugaison. Il y en a énormément dans la langue française, et l'usage s'étend au participe présent, mais l'abus peut être … gênant.

Answer (score -2):

En fait, ce n'est pas un adjectif, mais un participe passé. C'est une phrase passive ("j'ai été vexé par xxxx").

L'imparfait a un autre sens que le passé composé, il y a une sensation de durée qui n'existe pas avec le passé composé.

Comment: Dans “J'ai été vexée”, *vexée* peut être un participe passé ou un adjectif. Le sens est à peu près le même mais pas tout à fait : le passé composé passif fait référence à l'action de vexer alors que l'adjectif fait référence à l'état qui en résulte. Sans autre contexte, je comprends la phrase comme une référence à l'état, donc *vexée* est bien un adjectif.

Comment: Non, vexe est un participe passe. Il peut etre considere comme adjectif s'il n'y a pas d'auxiliaire. Ici, c'est une phrase passive. C'est evident pour toute personne connaissnat un peu la langue francaise.

Comment: *Vexée* est bien sûr un participe passé étymologiquement parlant, mais il est utilisé comme adjectif. On peut voir que c'est un adjectif dans d'autres phrases voisines où *vexée* ne peut pas s'analyser comme faisant partie du verbe, comme « elle paraissait vexée » ou « j'ai été vexée de ne pas y avoir pensé ».

Comment: Oui, dans ce cas, il s'agit du participe passe qui fonctionne comme un adjectif, mais ca reste... un participe passe. Et dans ce cas precis, il s'agit, encore une fois, d'une phrase passive. Je ne vois pas ce qui est complique a comprendre (une petite recherche sur Internet le montre aussi tres facilement, comme https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic681-adjectif-et-participe-passe.html).

Comment: Ben justement: “2 LE PARTICIPE PASSE EMPLOYE ADJECTIVEMENT SE RECONNAIT A DIVERS CRITERES : […] c) la possibilité d’avoir des DEGRES D’INTENSITE ; […] f) la possibilité d’avoir une EXPANSION (d’adjectif) ;”

Comment: C'est donc bien premierement un participe passe, merci de l'avoir cite. Maintenant, une fois de plus, dans ce contexte, c'est le voix passive, et donc premierement un emploi de participe passe.

Comment: Il faudrait peut être tenir compte du fait que le TLFi ne mentionne pas l'adjectif « vexé » alors qu'il mentionne « divisé » comme étant à la fois un participe passé et un adjectif ; cela montre qu'il y a toujours matière à discussion en ce qui concerne ce participe passé.

Comment: Voici ce que le TLFi stipule : Au part. passé. Piqué au vif, fâché. Il trouva le général Giraud vexé de n'avoir pu, au moment du débarquement, décider l'armée à le suivre (...), humilié de n'avoir de fonctions qu'en vertu des décisions de Darlan . On voit dans ce dernier exemple que même sans auxiliaire il n'est encore question que de participe passé.